# substringFromIndex is returning null

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

I want to get last 2 characters of a string. I am using substringFromIndex method. Which always returns null. I have made sure that string is not empty or null. Below is the code

```
self.weightUnitString = [weightString substringFromIndex: [weightString       length]-2];
NSLog(@"loadInfoToEdit weightString: %@", weightString);
NSLog(@"loadInfoToEdit weightUnit: %@", self.weightUnitString);
```

log:
    2015-11-03 21:34:53.351 Nephrotic Syndrome[822:142557] loadInfoToEdit    weightString: 35.2mg
    2015-11-03 21:34:53.351 Nephrotic Syndrome[822:142557] loadInfoToEdit weightUnit: (null)

this is making me crazy for past 2 hours.

Comment: Your example works pretty fine for me, I'm getting second log - "loadInfoToEdit weightUnit: mg".
You just missing something pretty easy. Btw do you have a strong for you property? No custom setters?

Comment: Thank you!! weightUnitString was declared as weak. Making it strong has solved my problem.

Comment: 2 hours that's pretty much :). Glad it helped.